# Add another column where there is no empty cell between based on the original column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I have a column D with some empty cells in between. For some reason, I'm not allowed to remove the empty cell manually for column D. I'm only allowed to create another column where all the code merges together without any empty cell in between referenced from column D which results in column E.

May I know is there any formula or VBA script for me to create a column E? Thank you.

Comment: Try this. https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-create-dynamic-drop-down-list-without-blank-in-excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to filter data which are not empty. Try below formula-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$1))/($A$2:$A$15<>""),ROW($A1))),"")
```

[image]

With <kbd>**Excel365**</kbd> you can use single filter formula.

```
=FILTER(A2:A12,A2:A12<>"","")
```

[image]